# Hibernate get object with linked objects

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, criteria

I have a problem with my hibernate mapping and queries.
I have an object A which have a relation with B and C.

The fetch mode is lazy (`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`) and I can't change it.
So my problem is next:

When I get an object by the get method (`hibernateDao.get`), I get the object A whitout relation with B and C.

If I create a criteria, I force the relation with `criteria.setFetchMode(...)` to get all with only query. But I have read on the web what it's not a good thing to make a criteria to get an object by primary key.

How to do this with the method get ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, this has bothing to do with J2EE. Not every question needs to be tagged with J2EE. [J2EE has been dead for years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Nomenclature.2C_standards.2C_and_specifications) anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fetch Profiles to have the fetch mode set as Lazy as default, and as Eager for a specific query: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3524

And if you are using a Hibernate version which doesn't supports Fetch Profiles, you can always do a HQL query which retrieves the tree you need, using joins.

> But I have read on the web what it's not a good thing to make a criteria to get an object by primary key.

I would be very careful before ruling out a solution just because you read somewhere that it's "bad". It may be a bad thing in the end, but if you don't understand why this is bad, you may be ruling out a solution which was made for your specific case ;-)

Comment: FetchProfile seems good but my version doesn't support it like annotation (presents with xml) (3.2) :( Criteria stay a good solution.

Comment: How about a HQL fetch option, which gives you a way of specifying what properties need to be fetched in one go (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html). This is supported in much older than 3.3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Hibernate.initialize();`

Example:

```
myEntity = hibernateDao.get...;
Hibernate.initialize(myEntity);
```

This will force hibernate to load all mapped entities in `myEntity`.